# Solving Differential Equation $y''=1+(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From the Question $y''=1+(y')^2$

I used Reduction of Order by taking $y'=z$ to get,

$$z\left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)=1+z^2$$

Solve the equation by Separation of Variable, to get

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln(1+z^2) = y+c $$

I tried to substitute $z=y'$ back to the equation above and solve the equation by Integration, but that was far very complex, so I got struck here. Please help

Comment: When $\frac{dy}{dx} = z$, then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{dz}{dx}$.

Comment: You could still easily go the next step $1+y'^2=1+z^2=C·e^{2y}$, after that this way really gets complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to solve $$y''=1+(y')^2$$

The usual thing is to replace $y'=v$ and therefore we get

$$v'=1+v^2.$$

This ODE can be solved by the usual methods, just use what you know. For example separation of variables i.e. solve for $v$

$$\int \frac{dv}{1+v^2} = \int dx$$

We get $v(x)=\tan(x+C)$ where $C$ is some constant.
Now resubstitute i.e. $$y'=v=\tan(x+C)$$

Just integrate both sides with respect to $x$ i.e.

$$y(x)=\int \tan(x+C) \ dx$$

This can be solved easily, for example use substitution $s=\cos(x+C)$

$$\int \tan(x+C) \ dx=-\int \frac{ds}{s}=-\log(s)=-\log(\cos(x+C))$$

Answer (score 3):

One thing to recognize is that the derivative of $\tan^{-1}$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(x) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$

We see here that we can rewrite our differential equation as

$$
\frac{dy'}{1 + (y')^2} \;\; =\;\; dx
$$

which can be solved as

$$
\tan^{-1}\left (y' \right ) \;\; =\;\; x + c.
$$

The tricky part now integrating $y'(x) = \tan(x+c)$.  Are you allowed to look this up?

Comment: I didn't realize the tan^-1 can be used there!! Got it now thanks very much